# How to reset the size of a image label with entry widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to reset the dimension of a image label after it was created in a function, using user-defined value entered in the entry widget. Basically I open the image file with 'Open File...' button and allow it to be resizable by mouse movement. Now I want to create a 'Set Dimension' button to reset the dimension of that image with user entry. But since the image label is created within the function display_image, is there a way that I can reset its dimension afterwards? I have commented the part that I have problem with. I am very new in using python and tkinter, really appreciate your help and patience.

```
def display_image():
    f = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title='Choose file',
        filetypes=[('png images', '.png'),
                   ('gif images', '.gif'),
                   ('jpeg images', '.jpg')]
    )

    def resize_image(event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height
        image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        label.config(image=img)
        label.image = img 

    image = Image.open(f)
    copy_of_image = image.copy()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(container, image=img)
    label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
    label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


def set_dimension():
    new_window = Toplevel(box1)
    new_window.title('Set Dimension')
    Label(new_window, text='width').grid(row=0, column=0)
    new_width = Entry(new_window, textvariable=StringVar())
    new_width.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(new_window, text='height').grid(row=0, column=2)
    new_height = Entry(new_window, textvariable=StringVar())
    new_height.grid(row=0, column=3)

    def reset():
        img_label.config(width=new_width, height=new_height) #here is the part that I have problem with

    Button(new_window, text='Reset', command=reset).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)


Button(box1, text='Open File...', command=display_image).grid(row=0, column=4)
Button(box1, text='Set Dimension', command=set_dimension).grid(row=1, column=4)
Button(box1, text='Save').grid(row=10, column=4)
```

Comment: Use `self.label.configure(image=<tkinter image>)` instead of resizing the label.